# \def function with arithmetic macro

Tags: fp, esami

I have been writing multiple equations to use for exam writing.  I have made some new macros that display a positive sign in front of an expression for positive numbers and display no sign for negative numbers.

Here is an example of a simple version of my definitions:

```
\def\dsignaddmulti#1#2#3#4{
\newcount\tmp
\newcount\ymp
\tmp=#1
\ymp=#3
\multiply\tmp by #2
\multiply\ymp by #4
\advance\tmp by \ymp
\FPifneg{\the\tmp}\else+\fi
}
```

I am trying to construct the same definition to multiply four numbers.  The definition works, but is displaying the number after the "sign", which I do not want.

Here is the non-working code:

```
\def\dsignmulti#1#2#3#4{
\newcount\tmp
\newcount\ymp
\tmp=#1
\ymp=#3
\multiply\tmp by #2
\multiply\ymp by #4
\multiply \tmp by \ymp
\FPifneg{\the\tmp} \else+\fi
}
```

Is there something that I am missing?

These are defined in my `esami.sty` file if that helps.

Sorry, I moved this from egreg's response:

@egreg:  I think I should be more clear about how I am using the function.  In the esami package, you can perform arithmetic on random numbers using the esempli function.  However, when placed inside of an equation, if the result is negative, I would end up with a positive sign following by a negative sign.

For example:

```
\begin{equation*}  x\dsignmulti{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}+\esempli{a*b+c*d}{1} \end{equation*}
```

If a*b+c*d is negative, the result has a positive and then negative sign following x.  The definition is supposed to display a positive sign for positive numbers and display nothing for negative numbers.  That way, I don't have two signs in a row.  This is what I would like to use in my equation:

```
\begin{equation*}  x\dsignmulti{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\esempli{a*b+c*d}{1} \end{equation*}
```

However, your code here:

```
\newcommand{\dsignmulti}[4]{%
  \@tempcnta=\numexpr#1*#2+#3*#4\relax
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@ +\fi\number\@tempcnta
}
```

solution outputs two numbers, when I only want to display the sign.  Is there an easy way to change this?

I apologize if I were unclear earlier.

Answer (score 9):

A basic error is, first of all, having `\newcount` in the definition of `\dsignmulti`: you are allocating two new counters at every usage of the macro.

The LaTeX kernel already provides counters for temporary usage, `\@tempcnta` and `\@tempcntb`; so a better definition would be

```
\newcommand{\dsignmulti}[4]{%
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \@tempcntb=#3\relax
  \multiply\@tempcnta by #2\relax
  \multiply\@tempcntb by #4\relax
  \advance\@tempcnta by \@tempcntb
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@ +\fi\number\@tempcnta
}
```

A possibly easier way would be using directly the `\numexpr` functionality:

```
\newcommand{\dsignmulti}[4]{%
  \@tempcnta=\numexpr#1*#2+#3*#4\relax
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@ +\fi\number\@tempcnta
}
```

You can even make it expandable, at the expense of speed:

```
\newcommand{\dsignmulti}[4]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1*#2+#3*#4\relax>\z@ +\fi
  \number\numexpr#1*#2+#3*#4\relax
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp), why not perform all the necessary calculation using its functionality?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\def\dsignaddmulti#1#2#3#4{
  ({#1}\times{#3})+({#2}\times{#4})=
  \FPeval\result{clip(((#1)*(#3))+((#2)*(#4)))}%
  \FPifneg\result\relax{\result}\else{+\result}\fi
}
\begin{document}
$\dsignaddmulti{1}{2}{3}{4}$

$\dsignaddmulti{-1}{-2}{3}{4}$
\end{document}
```

Of course, the above can be improved, but it's just to showcase what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use e-tex arithmetic so there is no need to use count registers at all, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\dsignmulti#1#2#3#4{%
\ifnum\numexpr#1*#2*#3*#4\relax>0{+}\fi
\the\numexpr#1*#2*#3*#4\relax}

\begin{document}

$\dsignmulti{1}{2}{3}{4}$

$\dsignmulti{1}{-2}{3}{4}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but while it works with actual numbers, it doesn't work with the random numbers I am using.  I set the random numbers using the following:'\FPsetpar{a}{-10}{10}[0]
\FPsetpar{b}{-10}{10}[{0,\a}]
\FPsetpar{c}{-10}{10}[{0,\a,\b}]
\FPsetpar{d}{-10}{10}[{0,\a,\b,\c}]' and the line below gives me two numbers: '$\dsignmulti{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}$'